# Beer Pairing: Stuffed Shells with Tomato Sauce

Tags: pairing, food

I'm making shells tonight, stuffed with ground beef, celery, onions, parmesan, ricotta, and breadcrumbs, topped with tomato sauce and mozzarella.

What style of beer, or individual beers themselves, would pair well with this?

Comment: Who down-voted? This is a great intersection topic for this community.

Comment: I down voted it because I respectfully disagree with you that this is a good topic. To me, this is an advice board for brewing. This question is about food pairing. To use a magazine metaphor, one is "Brew Your Own" and the other is "Food and Wine Magazine".  Related subjects but off topic, IMHO.  The lack of responses tends to reinforce my opinion.

Comment: @TinCoyote Actually, this site is meant to be about all things beer related, not just brewing. We started off with the homebrewing questions because that's what people know, but we wanted to have more information than just brewing related. Here's our press release: http://blog.brewadvice.com/post/295629853. But, the lack of responses and the general feeling that this is meant to be just for homebrewing means we need to get more non-brewing questions in here!

Comment: Fair enough.  I will keep that in mind.

Comment: OK PJ I just asked a non brewing question.  But does this mean you expect the site to compete with sights like BeerAdvocate?  I personally like this format in the homebrewing context.

Comment: @brewchez In the same way I expect this site to compete with HBT or other similar sites. It's a different format, so it's a different form of competition. I think asking questions like "How should I store beer" or "What does this beer pair well with" are great. I don't think questions like "Where do you see the industry going" or "How about that Cigar City email" fit here. But it's not my community, it's our community. We'll see where it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late to enjoy with red sauce and shells, Paulaner's Special extra dry pils is perfect for food with a nice tomato-garlic flavor proflie.  Nice to start with about 6%abv.  As far as the debate about style about the website, I am here for info, with potentially friends added.  If you don't serve beer with homecooked food and you brew, you may not need the info provided by questions like this.  Let the folks who enjoy cooking ask them.

Comment: and +1 on the style answer too. welcome to the site, mike

Answer (score 2):

Red sauce goes well with Pilsner and lighter IPAs.  Harpoon IPA would work well here as its relatively wimpy in the bitterness spectrum.
The next thing to try if you wanted something different.  Belgian Tripel would work well with red sauce too.